# Why some gradle tasks are inaccessible?

Tags: gradle

`gradlew tasks` gives me these tasks (amongst others):

```
assemble - Assembles all variants of all applications and secondary packages.
assembleAndroidTest - Assembles all the Test applications.
assembleDebug - Assembles all Debug builds.
assembleRelease - Assembles all Release builds.
build - Assembles and tests this project.
buildDependents - Assembles and tests this project and all projects that depend on it.
buildNeeded - Assembles and tests this project and all projects it depends on.
clean - Deletes the build directory.
cleanBuildCache - Deletes the build cache directory.
compileDebugAndroidTestSources
compileDebugSources
compileDebugUnitTestSources
compileReleaseSources
compileReleaseUnitTestSources
mockableAndroidJar - Creates a version of android.jar that's suitable for unit tests.
```

I can add additional code to say, `assemble`, like this:

```
assemble {
    doFirst {
        println "hello"
    }
}
```

but can't do it with many others from this list, for example, trying to add to `assembleDebug` gives me this error:

```
Error:(65, 0) Could not find method assembleDebug() for arguments [build_6s1kvuwgpamstoh3d4xsg1ndv$_run_closure3@13494795] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite easy to explain. When you run gradle script it's evaluated in order of declaration. But - sometimes, and android project is a good example - you don't (and can't) know what tasks can be created because they're based on the content of project (files, variants, whatever). So, these tasks are being created no sooner than the **whole project is evaluated**. That's why you can't *access* them in `build.gradle` - because the project evaluation isn't finished yet.

Now, if you know that a task named `assembleDebug` will be created you can use `[afterEvaluate`][1](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#afterEvaluate(groovy.lang.Closure)) to configure the task after evaluation. At this time the whole project is evaluated and all the tasks are added/generated.

So:

```
project.afterEvaluate {
   assembleDebug {
      doFirst {
         println "hello"
      }
   }
}
```